# Is Absolute Continuity can be inferred from an Atomless Probability Space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I have not deep knowledge in measure theory, and I am wondering if one could help me with this question.

Based on what is defined in Wikipedia, It turns out that non-atomic measures actually have a continuum of values. It can be proved that if ${\displaystyle\mu }$  is a non-atomic measure and ${\displaystyle A}$ is a measurable set with ${\displaystyle \mu (A)>0,}$ then for any real number ${\displaystyle b}$ satisfying ${\displaystyle \mu (A)\geq b\geq 0}$ there exists a measurable subset ${\displaystyle B}$ of ${\displaystyle A}$ such that
${\displaystyle \mu (B)=b.}$

Here is the question:

Let $(\Omega,M,\mu)$ is an atomless probability space and $B(\Omega)$ be the space of all bounded random variable on $\Omega$, if $\nu:B(\Omega)\to R$ is a finite measure on $M$ wrt $\mu$. Can we say that there exists a finite valued measurable function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that: $\nu(E)=\int_Efd\mu$ (Like what we have in the Radon-Nikodym Theorem)?

Comment: The Cantor function $F$ provides a counter-example. There is a measure $\nu $ on $[0,1]$ such that $\nu ([0,x])=F(x)$ . This measure is non-atomic and singular w.r.t Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Sam2n: What do you mean by a measure $\nu$ being finite with respect to an other measure $\mu$? If you meant to say that $\mu(A)<\infty$ implies $\nu(A)<\infty$, then of course your question can be answer in the negative.

Comment: Thank you @OliverDiaz, Yes you mention correctly about wrt. Now the question is, When that integral is valid?